# Create a PDF/A file with NetOffice

Tags: c#, pdfa, netoffice

I create my PDF file with:

```
ExportAsFixedFormat(pdffilename, WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatPDF);
```

but i need a PDF/A PDF. Is there a way to get this done with NetOffice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Document.ExportAsFixedFormat` overload with `useISO19005_1` parameter.

```
newDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat(pdfFilename, WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatPDF,
  false, WdExportOptimizeFor.wdExportOptimizeForPrint,
  WdExportRange.wdExportAllDocument, 0, 0,
  WdExportItem.wdExportDocumentContent, true, false,
  WdExportCreateBookmarks.wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, true, true,
  useISO19005_1: true);
```